# What is the rationale behind the content of a beacon chain's block?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, beacon-nodes

In this question where I asked [What exactly is the content of blocks on the beacon chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115594/what-exactly-is-the-content-of-blocks-on-the-beacon-chain) I got pointed to the data structure representing the content of the beacon chain, which is:

```
class BeaconBlockBody(Container):
    randao_reveal: BLSSignature
    eth1_data: Eth1Data  # Eth1 data vote
    graffiti: Bytes32  # Arbitrary data
    # Operations
    proposer_slashings: List[ProposerSlashing, MAX_PROPOSER_SLASHINGS]
    attester_slashings: List[AttesterSlashing, MAX_ATTESTER_SLASHINGS]
    attestations: List[Attestation, MAX_ATTESTATIONS]
    deposits: List[Deposit, MAX_DEPOSITS]
    voluntary_exits: List[SignedVoluntaryExit, MAX_VOLUNTARY_EXITS]
    sync_aggregate: SyncAggregate  # [New in Altair]
```

as per https://eth2book.info/altair/annotated-spec#beaconblockbody

What I am now failing to understand is the reason behind this content, and how the progressive tick of the blockchain requires them.

For Bitcoin or PoW Ethereum, I sort of understand the why of what goes inside the block. Basically in a period of time, transactions occurs in the network and needs to be added to the block. Right now, with the current beacon chain without the merge, I do not seem to understand the rational of what moves the beacon chain forward.

Anyone care to explain the changes that goes on in the 12 seconds allotted to a slot that needs to be kept in the beacon chain? and why so?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132525/discussion-on-question-by-finlay-weber-what-is-the-rationale-behind-the-content).