# Will Beacon node end up supporting smart contracts?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, beacon-nodes

I am aware that part of the PoS migration is the Phase 2, which will introduce the Smart Contract Execution. What is not clear though is if beacon nodes would be expanded to support smart contract execution when the time comes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution will remain with execution layer clients (the "eth1 clients" like Geth), also called execution engine.

Beacon nodes ("eth2 clients"), also called consensus layer clients (or consensus engine), will invoke APIs on the execution engine.

[image]

https://blog.ethereum.org/2021/11/29/how-the-merge-impacts-app-layer/ has further resources.

Comment: Hmm won't that complicate the setup? so you need to run beacon chain <which you get rewarded for> as well as clients like Geth <which when proof of work is switched off, you won't get rewarded for>?

Comment: Most nodes currently aren't block producers (miners/validators) and they can be a [light client](https://github.com/ethereum/consensus-specs/blob/dev/specs/altair/sync-protocol.md). But to produce blocks, yes need to run both clients: in future it may appear more like one package to user. BTW happy helping answering your questions here and I think your questions are very helpful for others in the future :) So I do hope you continue posting your good questions here, but if it's too slow here, check out the Discord in this [post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/03/31/eth2-quick-update-no-10/).

Comment: Previous comment was at the limit. Just found this [light client post](https://hackmd.io/@benjaminion/wnie2_211217#Light-client-corner) from a few days ago. (The Discord has many channels, including about light clients.)